# Pokemon Go login doesn't work on data but works on wifi

Tags: pokemon-go

I have a Galaxy S4 and I have issues running Pokemon Go.

It will not login using data, only wifi. So I connect on wifi at home, then go out and switch to data. It is fine.

But if the game needs to be restarted, it just gets hung on the google account login. It only works on wifi to get into the game.

Possibly related/unrelated: incense and lures do not work. People see stuff at lures, but I never do. They just do not work for me for some reason.

Comment: your second question is a distinct problem and you probably should edit it out. I'd recommend you ask it separately but I'm pretty sure it's a duplicate and the answer is elsewhere on this site already.

Comment: I've had the opposite happen to me. Data -> wifi: fine and no issues.  Wifi -> Data: app needs to be restarted and reconnected.  I'm using Sprint here, but I think it might be a phone or carrier issue.

Comment: https://m.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4tc8op/fix_pokémon_go_only_works_in_wifi/
Solved

Answer (score 1):

I've had this same issue the past few days. I've literally just tried the app reset and it's worked instantly. Go to application on settings. Then app manager. Then there should be a 'more' option or just the straight up option of pressing app preference reset (might be worded differently) and it should work straight away !!!

Answer (score 0):

After 3 weeks of having the exact same problem I finally fixed it :) 
Settings - app manager - reset all app preferences (something like that, my phone is not in English)

Good luck!

Comment: If you give an explanation how you did it, what phone you have and what it looks like, that would be a more appropriate answer